# What is the number of electrons being transferred in electrolysis of aluminum oxide?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis, reduction-potential

$$\ce{ 2/3 Al2O3 -> 4/3 Al +O2}$$

As we know, to find the Gibbs free energy, we need to use this formula:

$$ G= -nFE^\circ$$

What would $n$ be in this case? After breaking it down into the half reactions $n = 12,$ but this doesn't seem right.

Comment: 12 is wrong indeed. But I think I understand how you got there. How do you break this into half-reactions, to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the misunderstanding arises from the fact that you treat $n$ as the same entity as the lowest common multiple (LCM) used to balance the net equation using half-reactions for the electrolysis of molten aluminium(III) oxide:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{cathode:} &\ce{Al^3+(melt) + 3 e- &-> Al^0(l)} &|\cdot4\tag{red}\\
&\text{anode:} &\ce{2 O^2-(melt) &-> O2^0(g) + 4 e-} &|\cdot3\tag{ox}\\
\hline
& &\ce{4 Al^3+ + 6 O^2- &-> 4 Al^0 + 3 O2^0}\tag{redox}
\end{align}
$$

or, finally, with the smallest whole-number coefficients:

$$\ce{2 Al2O3(l) -> 4 Al(l) + 3 O2(g)}\label{rxn:R1}\tag{R1}$$

as well as normalized to a single [formula unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_unit):

$$\ce{Al2O3(l) -> 2 Al(l) + 3/2 O2(g)}\label{rxn:R2}\tag{R2}$$

In the equation

$$Δ_\mathrm rG = -nFE$$

$n$ is the number that matches the amount of electrons (in mol — since we are using *molar convention* for Gibbs free energy) transferred in the balanced equation from a reducing agent to an oxidizing agent.
From the balanced reaction \eqref{rxn:R2} it is evident that the number of electrons $n$ transferred from $\ce{O^2-}$ to $\ce{Al^3+}$ is $3 \cdot 2 = 6,$ where $3$ is the number of oxygens per formula unit, and $2$ is the number of electrons each oxygen donates.

Comment: But my textbooks says n=4?

Comment: @Leah I suspect your textbook is not correct, but could you please provide a reference? What textbook and what page number? It's important to see the context.